# Does the C++ standard guarantee that std::uintmax_t can hold all values of std::size_t?

Tags: c++, c++11

Does the C++ standard guarantee (either by explicitly stating it or implicitly by logical deduction) that `std::uintmax_t` can hold all values of `std::size_t`?

Or is it possible for `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()` to be larger than `std::numeric_limits<std::uintmax_t>::max()`?

Comment: in old versions of GCC, `std::size_t` is (wrongly) signed. So: not always, but it would still map to a unique value so you can go back & forth with no issue. More likely is that `size_t` is shorter than `uintmax_t`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes.

`size_t` is defined to be an unsigned integer type large enough to contain the size of any object. `uintmax_t` is defined to be able to store any value of any unsigned integer type. So if `size_t` can store it, `uintmax_t` can store it.

Definition of `size_t` from C++11 §18.2:

> The type size_t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.

Definition of `uintmax_t` from C99 §7.18.1.5 (it is included in C++ by normative reference):

> The following type designates an unsigned integer type capable of representing any value
>   of any unsigned integer type:
>
> ```
> uintmax_t
> ```

Comment: Right. By *definition*, `uintmax_t` is *the largest* unsigned integer type, and `size_t` as *an* unsigned integer type - by deduction, we can say that `uintmax_t` *must* be able to hold all values of `size_t`.

Comment: Could somebody find the C99 section number for that `uintmax_t` definition for me? I don't have a copy with me. Thanks.

Comment: Section 7.18.1.5 in C99 (7.20.1.5 in C2011).

Comment: @sftrabbit: Thank you for your precise answer. Exactly what I was looking for.