# can (u)intmax_t hold a function pointer?

Tags: c

Is a `uintmax_t` guarantee to be large enought to hold a function pointer?

i know this:

> The following type designates an unsigned integer type capable of
>   representing any value of any unsigned integer type:
>
> ```
> uintmax_t
> ```

and

> The following type designates an unsigned integer type with the
>   property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type,
>   then converted back to a pointer to void, and the result will compare
>   equal to the original pointer: uintptr_t

and that a void-Pointer is may not large enought to hold a function pointer, so a uintptr_t is may also not large enough to hold a function pointer.

Comment: I'd think it would have to be large enough, but I can't find supporting documentation.  This question might be relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15823217/does-the-c-standard-guarantee-that-stduintmax-t-can-hold-all-values-of-std

Comment: If the standard doesn't say so, then I guess the answer is no.  (AFAIK, the standard doesn't permit you to do any conversion/wackiness with function pointers.)

Comment: Conversion of a function pointer to an integer or an object pointer is undefined behaviour. This includes `void *`.

Comment: @olaf why, what part of the standard say that?

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 - Rather, the standard only lists defined behaviours (it doesn't say anything about converting function pointers, thus it is undefined).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth clarified that already. A function is not an object (see the definition in the standard).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  It seems trivial - but it isn't.

Comment: I found this obscure link that contains explicit and detailed information about do's, don'ts, techniques etc. _[all about function pointers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.cbclx01/cplr242.htm)_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not in general. `void*` and in consequence `[u]intptr_t` are only guaranteed to be wide enough to hold *object pointers*, that is pointers to object types. Function pointers may, on some platforms, be wider and comprise more information than just an entry point to the function. So on such platforms a `void*` or `uintptr_t` has not enough bits to represent all information that would be needed.

On many platforms, function pointers have the same width as object pointers, though, and they may even allow to convert from one to another. But this is an extension of the C standard and you'd have to check with your platform documentation.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such guarantee in the C standard.

First, there is no guarantee that any pointer can be losslessly converted to an integer type (except a NULL pointer). It is true that `uintptr_t` must be able to losslessly represent a void pointer (and thus any onject pointer). However, there is no guarantee that an implementation has `uintptr_t`, since it and `intptr_t` are optional (last sentence of § 7.20.1.4).

Second, a function pointer is not an object pointer, and it is not necessarily possible to convert one to a void pointer and back. So even if `uintptr_t` does exist, it might not be big enough to hold a function pointer.

On an X/Open System Interface (XSI) compatible implementation (most Posix systems), you must be able to convert between void pointers and function pointers, and uintptr_t must exist. So in that case, you do have the guarantee. (The convertibility between void and function pointers is required by the `dlsym` system interface, which was moved from XSI to base Posix in Issue 7 (2008). However, the existence of uintptr_t continues to be an XSI extension.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is a uintmax_t guarantee to be large enough to hold a function pointer?

No guaranteed way as well answered by others.

---

Yet the size of a function pointer does exist and it does have a bit pattern.  If sufficiently large, `uintmax_t` could hold the pointer's bit pattern (and maybe more).  This size test could be assessed at compile time.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int foo(int x) {
 return x+x;
}

int main(void) {
  union {
    uintmax_t um;
    int (*fp)(int);
  } u  = {0};
  assert(sizeof u.um >= sizeof u.fp);  // This assertion may fail
  u.fp = foo;

  uintmax_t save = u.um;
  printf("%ju\n", save);

  u.um = save;
  printf("%d\n", (*u.fp)(42));

  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
4198816
84
```